# How Display Specific Content For Opera Mini Users Only In WordPress

Tags: wordpress, opera, user-agent, ads

I've googled extensively but still can't find a working solution.

The thing is I was wondering if there's a way I could configure my wordpress theme to detect Opera Mini users and show them a particular ad/content while showing a different one to other browser users as a fallback.

Over 80% of my mobile traffic is Opera Mini based and I'd like to monetize that effectively.

I'm guessing this could be done with PHP but I don't know how to go about coding it.

Answer (score 3):

Test the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] global to see if it contains the string "Opera Mini".

[PHP Manual: $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Or, **even better**

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
```

which returns an array of browser info. The 'browser' key contains the actual browser name.

[PHP manual: get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

The simplest method would be to wrap specific content in a condition based on either of these possibilities.

For example:

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
if ($browser == "Opera Mini") {
    // display image
} else {
    // display other image
}
```

Comment: I tried the code above but I'm getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'. Could you please paste the complete PHP code that I should add to my theme file? Thanks

Comment: There's no error in this code, Chuks, look elsewhere.. +1 for that function, thx!

Comment: @Brasofilo: Look elsewhere for what please? Could you please post with the full code with the php tags 'cause i don't know why it keeps throwing up an error :(

Comment: @UdegbunamChuks, you are the one who have a "full code" :) - I just said that this snippet is ok. You'll have to find your way to get the faulty line in your code. For each opening `{` corresponds an ending `}`, or the [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). When developing always have [`WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and also look in the server PHP `error_log` to troubleshoot your code errors. [edit: if there's only one line after an `if` or `foreach`, the opening and closing brackets can be omitted]

Comment: Gosh I'm feeling pretty retarded right now. *covers face* I've gone through the code but can't find a reason for the Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' error on line 6. Here's the full code guys.http://www.strictlyonlinebiz.com/php.txt Maybe I'm blind to what's causing the error

Comment: You can't reference JavaScript or HTML inside PHP willy nilly. You have to output it using PHP's echo or print/printf commands. Either that or place the non-PHP stuff outside the <?php ... ?> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Time to brush up on your php basics, UdegbunamChuks.

```
<?php

$isOperaMini = <<<HEREDOC
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://goo.gl/RopBp">
<img src="http://www.patchworkoftips.com/wp-content/themes/adclerum3/images/BBMobile.jpg" title="Buy Cheap BlackBerry Phones" alt="Buy Cheap BlackBerry Phones">
</a>
HEREDOC;

$notOperaMini = <<<HEREDOC
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-4322797130930030";
/* Patchwork Below Post Mobile */
google_ad_slot = "1887667973";
google_ad_width = 300;
google_ad_height = 250;
//-->
</script>
HEREDOC;

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
if ($browser == "Opera Mini") {
    echo $isOperaMini;
} else {
    echo $notOperaMini;
}

?>
```

Comment: While I understand what you're trying to do here, this is no place for a full-on PHP tutorial. The OP obviously needs to start someplace else, instead of winging it one block of code at a time.

Comment: @Chris Herbert: Thanks man. I'll try that and like Ian Atkin I guess I have to get back to my PHP basics asap ;)